# Setting Magento event data

Tags: magento

So, no one has a really good explanation on how to set event data.  I've read a good number of posts about getEvent, and have only found the Magento docs on setEvent.

How do I set event data (return it from the observer) on *before_save?

## code

```
public function onCategorySaveBefore($observer)
{
    $rules = Mage::getResourceModel('categoryrules/rules_collection');
    $keepSpecialFlag = 1;
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $categoryId = $event->getCategory()->getId();
    foreach ($rules as $r) {
        if ( $r['category_id'] != $categoryId ) {
            $keepSpecialFlag = 0;
        }
    }

    if ($keepSpecialFlag==0) {
#code needs saved here.  something like $event->setData('rogue_category_rule', 0);
    }
    return;
}
```

## config.xml

```
<catalog_category_save_before>
    <observers>
        <categoryrules>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>categoryrules/observer</class>
            <method>onCategorySaveBefore</method>
        </categoryrules>
    </observers>
</catalog_category_save_before>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Varien_Event` extends `Varien_Object`, so you can set any parameter by calling

```
$observer->getEvent()->setData('you_parameter', 'some_ value');
```

or

```
$observer->getEvent()->setYourParameter('some_ value');
```

**EDIT**:
But you should also check `Mage_Core_Model_App::dispatchEvent` method imlpementation. Maybe Magento instantiates new event for each observer. And it's really bad idea to set some values into event. Usually event is immutable object.

Comment: Thank you Serjio.  I just figured this out not too long ago.  Appreciate the answer, however!